# in BASH, how to find files with no file.extension

Tags: bash, file, search, find, ls

```
echo >tst
echo >tst.
echo >tst.txt
echo >tst.html
echo >tst.ms.html
echo >tst.ms..html

find -maxdepth 1  -type f -name "*."
```

I get only:
./tst.

I want to get the one file
./tst
sans trailing dot

Comment: Maybe `find . -type f \! -name '*.*'` (that is, "find all files whose name does not contain a `.`")?

Comment: @larsks Exactly what is listed here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144208/find-files-without-extension

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?: Filenames which do **not** contain a dot? What is with filenames which have a dot at the first or as the last character?

Answer (score 0):

Using only `bash`

```
shopt -s extglob
echo !(*.*)
```

it won't exclude dirs though

Answer (score -1):

One solution in this case is use `!` to exclude all the names with any period in their names:

```bash
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.*"
```

which returns only `./tst`.

Comment: This answer looks strangely familiar...almost like someone else posted the same thing.

Comment: Strange how it takes more than a minute to answer a question with no response and when you hit submit you see a comment made to the question 1 min ago

Comment: Yes, that's the nature of the site.